# Convert lists of tuples to an array, where the first element in each tuple is the array index?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In Python, how do I convert a several lists of tuples to an array, where the first element in each tuple is the array index?  Additionally, not every list has tuples for every item, and I want those missing items to be filled with 0.

So I have:

```
a = [(0, 2.45), (1, 3.25), (2, 5.34)]
b = [(0, 7.46), (1, 5.64), (3, 3.45)]
c = [(0, 9.65), (1, 7.22)]
```

And I want:

```
somefun(a, b, c)
>>> array([(2.45, 3.25, 5.34, 0.  ), (7.46, 5.64, 0.  , 3.45), (9.65, 7.22, 0.  , 0.  ])
```

I have a solution right now that iterates through the lists, creates structured arrays with assigned columns, and then uses `numpy.lib.refunction.stack_array()`, but this approach is quite slow:

```
from numpy.lib import refunctions as rfn

row_list = []
for row in [a, b]:
    index = [(str(i[0]), 'f4') for i in row]
    value = [tuple([i[1] for i in row])]
    row_list.append(np.array(value, dtype=index))

result = np.ma.filled(rfn.stack_arrays(row_list, usemask=True), fill_value = 0)
```

I have tens of thousands of such lists that I want to combine into an array, so I am looking for something quicker.  Maybe there is a more apt `numpy` method that I am not aware of.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there a maximum length that can be assumed for these lists? Can we assume, for example, that these lists will not be more than 10 tuples long?

Comment: Can we assume that, in each list, no two tuples will have the same first element?

Comment: There is a maximum length (although it could be in the hundreds), and we can assume that no two tuples will have the same first element.

Comment: Can we assume that in each list, the tuples will always be sorted by increasing first element? (as seems to be the case in your sample data)

Comment: Yes, that is the case for my application

Comment: Do you need the final result only as a structured array? Or is an ordinary numpy array (non-structured one) ok?

Comment: You mentioned "tens of thousands of lists". Can I assume that the number of lists is known beforehand (before starting to process the lists)? (Or do we know that only after receiving the last list?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following function:

```
from itertools import chain

a = [(0, 2.45), (1, 3.25), (2, 5.34)]
b = [(0, 7.46), (1, 5.64), (3, 3.45)]
c = [(0, 9.65), (1, 7.22)]

def func(*lists):
    max_ind = max(ind for ind, _ in chain.from_iterable(lists))
    result = []
    for l in lists:
        d = dict(l)
        t = tuple(d.get(ind, 0.) for ind in range(max_ind + 1))
        result.append(t)
    return result

print(func(a, b, c))
# [(2.45, 3.25, 5.34, 0.0), (7.46, 5.64, 0.0, 3.45), (9.65, 7.22, 0.0, 0.0)]
```

Alternatively you can use `itemgetter()` with `defaultdict()`:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

def func(*lists):
    max_ind = max(ind for ind, _ in chain.from_iterable(lists))
    iget = itemgetter(*range(max_ind + 1))
    return [iget(defaultdict(float, l)) for l in lists]

print(func(a, b, c))
# [(2.45, 3.25, 5.34, 0.0), (7.46, 5.64, 0.0, 3.45), (9.65, 7.22, 0.0, 0.0)]
```

Comment: I think you can use "get() with default 0" from the dictionary, to construct your tuple.

Comment: @fountainhead Nice idea! Thank you!